# exclude multiple files with one sentence in grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I wanna exclude multiple files with specific file name in grunt copy task, and the config now is this:

```
src: [
    '**',
    '!**/{master, client, socket}.*',
    '!**/*.map'
]
```

but it only excludes file named with "master". It there a way to exclude all of this files in one declaration? Or can I use regular expression here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space character inside the expression.

This will work

```
src: [
    '**',
    '!**/{master,client,socket}.*',
    '!**/*.map'
]
```